# submit name is not POSTing from inside modal

Tags: html, django, forms

I have an html form posting to a django view. There are 2 submit inputs on this form:

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add rows"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Application"/>
```

In my view, I expect to be able to decide which button was click using something like:

```
if 'add' in request.POST:
    # Do some stuff
else:
    # Do some different stuff
```

So far, so simple. here's the fun bit- this page is displayed in a modal. If I load the modal and hit a submit button, the input name is not getting posted.
However, if I load the html outside of the modal, it is getting posted.

What on earth am I missing here?

Comment: Those sound like 2 very different operations. I'm not sure they should even be in the same form or access the same view.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your form in a modal by handling it through some jQuery.

```
$(function(){
  $('#tagetForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: , //url to submit form to
      type: 'POST',
      data: $('#targetForm').serialize(), //Or hash data how you want it
      success: function(data){
        //handle successful submit
      }
    });
  });
});
```